# Definite Integral, Piecewise, Error

Tags: integral-equations, piecewise

I am trying to evaluate the following:

```
myExpression=Piecewise[{{-c E^(c s)-(E^(-((-s+\[Alpha]+q \[Beta])^2/(2 (\[Beta]^2 \[Sigma]q^2+\[Sigma]s^2)))) v \[Beta])/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] Sqrt[\[Beta]^2 \[Sigma]q^2+\[Sigma]s^2]),\[Beta]!=0},{-c E^(c s),\[Beta]==0}}]
Integrate[myExpression,s]
```

However, when I try to make this Integral definite, by using {s,0,z}, I get the following error:

```
Integrate::pwrl: "Unable to prove that integration limits {0,z} are real. Adding assumptions may help"
```

I do not wish to change the expression of this integral, nor do I care for some cheap trick which removes the error message (like `Quiet`). I simply want to know where this error comes from, and what additional information about my variabales *Mathematica* would like to know.

Thanks!
Laurens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add as an option

```
Integrate[myExpression, {s, 0, z}, Assumptions -> z > 0]
```

The reason why you got this error is because by default, *Mathematica* does not assume that the variable $z$ is a real number.  It is trying to find an analytic solution to the integral for general complex $z$.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know the dummy variables were assumed to be complex by default.

Comment: For the record (http://i.stack.imgur.com/H1YHW.png) :)

Comment: 666 you mean? ;)